# How can I escape characters inside of this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

I have this function which will validate an email address. jsLint gives an error with the regular expression complaining about some of the characters being un-escaped.

Is there a way to correctly escape them?

```
var validateEmail = function(elementValue){
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
};
```

Comment: This has been answered but as an a-side Rexex.Escape is a handy function for escaping special chars in regex expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regular expression you are using *is* valid. But I guess JSLint complains about the missing escape sign in front of `-` in the character classes:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

Escaping the `-` inside a character class is only required if it is not at the begin or end of the character class or if it is not denoting a range when used between two characters.

Here are some examples that are valid:

```
/[-xyz]/    // "-", "x", "y", "z"
/[xyz-]/    // the same as above
/[-]/       // "-"
/[a-z-]/    // "a"-"z", "-"
/[a-b-c]/   // "a"-"b", "-", "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing immediately what needs to be escaped. You might want to try `/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i` for your Regex. I just neatened it a little and added `+` and `%` to the first field.